# Prove that if $k\in \mathbb{N}, n=3k \rightarrow \frac{n!}{(3!)^k} \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Prove using a combinatoric argument that if $k\in \mathbb{N}, n=3k \rightarrow \frac{n!}{(3!)^k} \in \mathbb{N}$
$$=\frac{(3k)!}{3^k2^k}$$

Any ideas are appreciated, I'm stuck here, thanks!

Comment: In other words, the problem is to show that if $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $(3k)!/(3!)^k \in \mathbb{N}$.  Is that right?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes pretty much, I don't know why they used that n on the book. And by the way, how do you write the proper N for naturals on MathJax?

Comment: You use `\mathbb{N}` for $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: $$\frac{(3k)!}{3^k2^k}=\frac{(3k)!}{6^k}=\frac{(3k)!}{(3!)^k}$$

Now, in how many ways can you arrange $3k$ things in a row where out of the $3k$ things, there are $k$ distinct things and each thing is present in triplets?

Comment: Although I liked the induction approaches much more, this would be the correct answer since it asks for a theoretical combinatorial argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Reducing $\cfrac{n!}{(3!)^k}$ to $\cfrac{(3k)!}{2^k3^k}$ is a good start.

If you use induction on $k$, the proof should be straightforward. The base case ($k=1$) is very easy, as the numerator and denominator will be the same number.

If we assume $\cfrac{(3k)!}{2^k3^k}$is equal to some integer $M$, consider the case $\cfrac{(3(k+1))!}{2^{k+1}3^{k+1}}=\cfrac{(3k+3)(3k+2)(3k+1)(3k!)}{6(2^k3^k)}=\cfrac{(3k+3)(3k+2)(3k+1)}{6}M$.

Can you think of where to go from here?

Comment: This was the solution I thought of.  Although it's not a “combinatorial argument.”

Comment: The question asks for a combinatorial argument. And this is not.

Comment: I just tried this method for the second part where it asks to generalize the result and I quickly realized that from that $(3k+3)(3k+2)(3k+1)$ you'll get a $27k^3$ and 27 is not divisible by 6, soo what's going on in here? Why is that?

Comment: Instead of expanding the expression, it is easier to note that $(3k+3)=3(k+1)$ (and so is divisible by 3) and that either $(3k+2)$ or $(3k+1)$ must be divisible by 2, so we can write $(3k+2)(3k+1)=2P$ for some integer $P$. So $(3k+3)(3k+2)(3k+1)=(3)(2)(k+1)(P)$ and is divisible by 6.

Answer (score 1):

A *non-combinatorial* argument:

Any three consecutive natural numbers contain at least one multiple of $2$ and at least one multiple of $3$ . So the product of any three consecutive natural numbers is divisible by $3\cdot 2=6$.

Now we can write $(3k)!$ as the product of $k$ groups of $3$ consecutive natural numbers.

So we can say that $6^k|(3k)!$.

The proof follows.

Answer (score 0):

Actually mathematical induction (after k) should work pretty well with this one.

1. for k = 1, is pretty obvious that $\frac{(3*1)!}{(3*2)}$ = 1, so it verifies.
2. we assume true for k-1, check for k. For k-1, we have that $\frac{(3*(k-1))!}{3^{k-1}*2^{k-1}}$ (I'll call this fraction "J") is in N. What do we have for k? For k, we have $\frac{(3*k)!}{3^k*2^k}$. But this is actually $\frac{(3*(k-1))! * (3k-2) * (3k-1)*3k}{3^{k-1}*2^{k-1}*3*2}$ = J * $\frac{(3k-2)*(3k-1)*3k}{3*2}$. We know that J is in N (we assumed it true for k-1), now it remains to show that $\frac{(3k-2)*(3k-1)*3k}{3*2}$ is in N. I hope this is pretty obvious, since is a multiplication of 3 consecutive numbers, on top, from which definitely one is divisible by 3 and one or two are divisible by 2. So the fraction is also in N. We proved for k, so the induction should be complete.

I hope is clear enough...